# The Specifications of SAML2 AssertionConsumerService endpoint are not valid

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, owin-middleware, sustainsys-saml2

I got the below error while I was trying to authenticate through IBM Security Access Manager (using Sustainsys.Saml2.Owin)

[image: Error Message]

Here is the [Link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4J57_6.2.0/com.ibm.tivoli.fim_bg.doc_6.2/messages/FBTSML218E.htm) of error code

I tested the code on another IDP https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/ and it's working.

Maybe the difference is with the test IDP (Stupidp) it was a solicited response but from IBM Security Access Manager was Unsolicited (Idp-initiated).

But I already set `AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true`

Here is the metadata that attached on IBM Security Access Manager

[image: SP Metadata]

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution I was sent a wrong metadata, the right one if you use SustainSys.Saml2 is to hit your SP URL "https://SP.com/Saml2" this will generate your SP metadata file.

The AssertionConsumerService was wrong was the action to be landed after login on the IDP, but the right one should be "https://SP/Saml2/Acs"